# CodeIgniter won't pass $data when loading via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, variables, mobile, undefined

I am working on a database-driven site where I want the URI segments of my links to load corresponding data from my database. The site is running on CodeIgniter 2.1.4 with JQuery Mobile loading pages via AJAX. Here is an example of my URLs.

site.com/browse (runs the index function, loading a list of Artists)

site.com/browse/artist/album (runs the artist function, passing the third URI segment album as a parameter to the Data Model, loading a list of that artist's albums)

I understand how to pass the ID from the URL to my Model to load the data and process that data into my view. When calling the index function of my Browse class, everything works as it should. I am able to create a list of artist. When calling the Artist function, the URI segment is being passed to the model and loading data, but $data does not seem to be passing to my view so I keep getting an undefined variable error when trying to display my data.

get_data.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Get_data extends CI_Model {

function getAllArtists() {

    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT DISTINCT ARTIST FROM data ORDER BY ARTIST');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
        $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}


function getAllAlbums($artist) {
    //Get artist from URI segment
    $artist = urldecode($this->uri->segment(3));
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT DISTINCT ALBUM, ARTIST FROM data WHERE ARTIST = "'.$artist.'" ORDER BY ALBUM');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
        $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}

}
```

browse Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Browse extends CI_Controller {

public function index(){
    //Page Data
    $data['title'] = 'Site: Browse';
    $this->load->model('get_data');
    $data['rows'] = $this->get_data->getAllArtists();
            $rows = $this->data['rows'];    

    //Page Views
    $this->load->view('t/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('p/browse', $data);
    $this->load->view('t/footer');

}

public function artist($artist){

    //URL Decode
    $artist = urldecode($artist);
    //Page Data
    $data['title'] = 'Site: '.$artist;

    //Load model and retrieve data from database
    $this->load->model('get_data');
    $this->data['rows'] = $this->get_data->getAllAlbums($artist);
    $rows = $this->data['rows'];      

    //Page Views
    $this->load->view('t/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('p/artist', $data);
    $this->load->view('t/footer');


}


public function album($album){

    //Page Data
    $data['title'] = 'site: '.urldecode($album);

    //Load model and retrieve data from database
    $this->load->model('get_data');
    $this->data['rows'] = $this->get_data->getAllSongs($album);
    $rows = $this->data['rows'];

    //Page Views
    $this->load->view('t/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('p/artist', $data);
    $this->load->view('t/footer');


    }



}
```

browse View (This works as it should):

```
<!-- Start content.php -->
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header" data-id="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.site.com/home" class="" data-transition="fade">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.site.com/browse" class="" data-transition="fade">Browse</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.site.com/about" class="" data-transition="fade">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"id ="toggle">&#9654;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- /jqm-header -->


<div data-role="content">

<ul id="song_list" data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
<?php foreach ($rows as $r) {?><li data-icon="false"><a data-transition="slide" href="http://www.site.com/browse/artist/<?php echo urlencode($r['ARTIST']); ?>"><?php echo $r['ARTIST']; ?></a></li><?php };?>
</ul>

</div>


<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>site.com</h4>
    <h5><?php echo $this->benchmark->elapsed_time();?></h5>
</div><!-- /jqm-footer -->
```

artist View (This gives me an error: Undefined variable "rows"):

```
<!-- Start content.php -->
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header" data-id="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.site.com/home" class="" data-transition="fade">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.site.com/browse" class="" data-transition="fade">Browse</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.site.com/about" class="" data-transition="fade">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"id ="toggle">&#9654;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- /jqm-header -->


<div data-role="content">

<ul id="song_list" data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
<li data-icon="false"><a data-rel="back">Back</a></li>
<?php foreach ($rows as $r) {?><li data-icon="false"><a data-transition="slide" href="http://www.site.com/browse/album/<?php echo urlencode($r['ALBUM']); ?>"><?php echo $r['ALBUM']; ?></a></li><?php };?>
</ul>

</div>


<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>site.com</h4>
    <h5><?php echo $this->benchmark->elapsed_time();?></h5>
</div><!-- /jqm-footer -->
```

This has been driving me insane. I had it working before and now I don't know what the problem is. I have disabled jQuery Mobile AJAX loading and it still gives me this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In model file, I dont think you need to use ' $artist = urldecode($this->uri->segment(3));' since you already pass it as parameter into model function. But you can try to use it in controller to get artist information. And I dot not see that you take any advantage of routing class in CodeIgniter. Not good practice of using such framework.

Comment: If you are extending CI_Controller, please write a function for example "`_render()`" that will take one parameter (or more depends on design). `_render()` should load views, later on you just do `$this->_render('/p/artist_view')`. (no `$data` need to be passed via function because its "globaly" set to `$this->data['whatever'];` Thats just a tip for you, now to the problem I think you are not passing right parameter to the views... in your design you sould pass whole $this->data as second parameter to the load_view function.

Comment: e.g. my render fcn looks like  `public function render( $view_path ) {

  $this->load->view('template/header_view');
  $this->load->view('template/navbar_view', $this->data);
  $this->load->view($view_path.'_view', $this->data);
  $this->load->view('template/footer_view');

 }` If I want to pass data to the view I just use `$this->data['title'] = 'Codeigniter';` anywhere in any controller that is extended by MY_Controller

Comment: If your calling the function via ajax, then you will need to return the view as data (using the third param), and then echo this out. `$foo = $this->load->view('t/header', $data, true); echo $foo;`

Comment: @web2kx Thanks. I realize I don't need  '$artist = urldecode($this->uri->segment(3));'. I just had it there sort of as a reminder to myself because I'm just still learning how to use CodeIgniter. By Routing class, do you mean setting my own URI routing rules?

Comment: @user2676292, you can check codeigniter user guide about uri routing. Here is the link: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html. It is just like setting up url rewrite in an easy format.